# Mongoose Validation error Path is required

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am receiving a 500 error when submitting a post request to an API I have created using express and mongoose. The error I receive is ...Error is ValidationError: userId: Path `userId` is required.

The request body I am passing is ..

```
{
  "order": [
    {
      "item": {
        "id": "p2",
        "title": "Scarf",
        "description": "Red Scarf",
        "price": 8
      },
      "quantity": 2,
      "totalItemCost": 16
    }
  ],
  "userId": "659e15b29fcef318fc03bde8"
}
```

My Create Order controller looks like …

```
export const createOrderController = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    try {
        const order = req.body;
        console.log('order is ' + JSON.stringify(order))
        let createdOrder = await createOrder({
            order
        })
        return res.status(200).json(createdOrder).end();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('Error is ' + error)
        return res.sendStatus(500)
    }
}
```

My data schemas and models for Orders are ..

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
})

const OrderItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    item: { type: productSchema, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    totalItemCost: { type: Number, required: true }
})

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    order: { type: [OrderItemSchema], required: true },
    userId: { type: String, required: true }
})

export const OrderModel = mongoose.model('order', OrderSchema);
export const createOrder = (createdOrder: Record<string, any>) => new OrderModel(createdOrder).save().then((order) => order.toObject())
```

I don't understand why it is not recognising the element userId as the console.log for the order in the create order controller clearly shows it as a top level element as is it is being passed in as payload.

I can get this to work if I change the assignment of the order const to..

```
const order = req.body.order
```

But then I have to make the userId element in schema not required and it obviously doesn't create the record with the userId.

I've seen other similar queries on here, but the problem and solution don't seem to match my particular case.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `console.log('body: ', req.body);` as the first statement in your `createOrderController ` function please.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Sure it looks like this .. 
body:  {
  order: [ { item: [Object], quantity: 2, totalItemCost: 16 } ],
  userId: '659e15b29fcef318fc03bde8'
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call  your `createOrder` function here:

```js
let createdOrder = await createOrder({
   order
})
```

You are wrapping `order` in an object which in JavaScript is shorthand that translates to:

```js
let createdOrder = await createOrder({
   order: order
})
```

So the contents of `req.body` is being assigned to the `order` property of your document and `userId` will be part of that `order` object. As far as mongoose is concerned there is no `userId` property being passed in.

What you want to do is this:

```js
let createdOrder = await createOrder(order);
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. Thanks for that. Probably should have worked that out myself :-).

Comment: @chucknor You're welcome. There was a bit of abstraction with how you are creating a new document, so easy to miss.